# USA for Africa song

Tags: pop

What could be the probable reasons for Rod Stewart, Brian Adams , Elton John, Sting not in this beautiful song?

The reason being there nationality is not American?

Thanks & Regards,

Prashant S Akerkar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"USA for Africa" was the American response to the ["Band Aid"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Band_Aid_(band)) project ( "Do They Know It's Christmas?", 1984) which featured mainly British and Irish artists, so almost all the artists on ["We Are the World"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/We_Are_the_World) are US-Americans (the founder of Band Aid, Bob Geldorf, who is Irish, sang in the chorus).
Rod Stewart, Elton John and Sting are British and Bryan Adams is Canadian.

Comment: Thank you. I couldn't locate Bob Geldorf in the chorus. Can you assist?

Comment: @PrashantAkerkar He's listed on the Wikipedia page